# Regular expression to match user@domain:port

Tags: php, regex

I have to match a string as user@domain:port. So it should allow domain or domain:port or user@domain or user@domain:port complete. Initially i had written multiple regular expressions to match some of these conditions as following:

```
preg_match('/^[A-z0-9_\-]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z.]{2,4}$/', $str) or preg_match('/^[A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z.]{2,4}$/', $str) or preg_match('/^[A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z.]{2,4}+([:][0-9]+)$/', $str)
```

but now i have to cover all conditions as above and i think there should be a single expression which will pass all conditions.

Can someone please tell me the correct regular exp to match all conditions with some explanation?

I want to do it in PHP.

Comment: is the domain always a .com or do you need all tld variants ? Do you need subdomains as well ?

Comment: I can't believe you made some research about that question (google it) and didn't found anything. Seriously.

Comment: It should accept all sorts of domain. I have edited my question. @Amarnasan of course i googled it before asking otherwise why would i put efforts typing entire questions if i had found it on google.

Comment: Can you post some of the sample strings

Comment: And what about the first entry you get (accidentally it's a SO entry) ? Don't you like it? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/mT6pR3/15) is something to help you

The regex

```
^(?:([\w-]+)@)?([\w-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z][\w-]+)(?::([0-9]{1,5}))?$
```

Should do what you want. Let's explain :
You first want to match (if it exist) a user followed by `@`. To match a word you can use `\w` but in your regex you specified that you wanted the char `-` wich isn't include in `\w` (but `_` is). So to match your user you will do :

```
(?:([\w-]*)@)?
```

Then you want to match a domain name

```
([\w-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z][\w-]+)
```

The domain name have to finish by at least one dot followed by a word (the top level domain). The top level domain doesn't begin by a digit (this rule was created based on the [usedTopLevelDomainList](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt)

And to finish you want to match a port wich is a 1-5 digit :

```
(?::([0-9]{0,5}))?
```

---

**As pointed out the regex can match IPv4 that aren't within the 255 max range.**
The regex to verify an IPv4 is :

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

[Source](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html). I've updated the previous regex to exclude the IP match from my regex and add a `OR` statement for the domain name to match either an IPv4 based on the above regex or a domain as I've defined it previously.

[Result](https://regex101.com/r/mT6pR3/14) with group to separate each part :

```
^(?:([\w-]+)@)?((?:[\w-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z][\w-]+)|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))(?::([0-9]{1,5}))?$
```

[Result](https://regex101.com/r/mT6pR3/13) without any group to just match valid case :

```
^(?:[\w-]+@)?(?:(?:[\w-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z][\w-]+)|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))(?::[0-9]{1,5})?$
```

Comment: It will match `user:45555`, too.

Comment: I forgot to espace the doc char in the middle of the regex. It's should be fine now

Comment: It will match only user also and i don't want that. I need to match either domain or user@domain i.e email or domain:port. One more thing, just came to my mind that domain can be IP address also.

Comment: @Raakesh: It does not match `user@domain`.

Comment: I've updated the awnser to include IP. The whole domain is now match at once and I do not separate things like .com from the rest of the domain name.

Comment: Edited once again since top level domain (the `.com`) can be greater than 3 chars

Comment: @naurel it matches user@127.0.0.500 also but it should not accept anything above 255 in IP address section. Am i wrong?

Comment: @stribizhev i don't need to match user@domain because domain is not a string but it should be a proper domain name.

Comment: Edited to match a valid IPv4 adress. You have to know it will not match IPv6

Comment: Edited once more with the non-capturing group

Comment: And final edit to match some special case inside the top level domain since they cannot begin by a digit but they can have some after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?:(?:[\w-]+@)?(?:[\w-]+)\.[\w.-]+(?::[0-9]{1,5})?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iP7pM6/3)

The problem I came across is that the first `user@` is optional for the second regex, but is obligatory for the 3rd part. My regex matches:

- `(?:(?:[\w-]+@)?(?:[\w-]+)\.[\w.-]+(?::[0-9]{1,5})?` -

  - `(?:[\w-]+@)?` - 1 or 0 sequences of 1 or more alphanumerics or `-` followed by `@`
  - `[\w-]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric characters or `-`
  - `\.[\w.-]+` - a literal dot followed by 1 or more alphanumeric characters, `.` or `-`
  - `(?::[0-9]{1,5})?` - 1 or 0 sequences of a colon followed by 1 to 5 digits

Comment: This is exactly what i want but i can accept only one answer so i accepted the previous one. I am not able to upvote you but for others that's perfect.

Comment: Thank you :) but i just saw in your answer that this expression will match user@domain also which i don't want. What i mean with domain is it should be proper domain name like xyz.com

Comment: It is easy, I removed the second alternative. Now, if there is any more I can help with, just feel free to drop a comment.

Comment: I need this to accept IP address also in domain name. So it should accept user@127.0.0.1 also or user@127.0.0.1:8080 or 127.0.0.1:8080 or 127.0.0.1. When i tried with your expression, its working okay but its accepting 127.0.0.5000:8080 also. Can you please suggest me one more time :)

Comment: Please try [`^(?!.*(?<=[.@])(?:25[6-9]|26[0-9]|[3-9][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4,})\b)(?:(?:[\w-]+@)?(?:[\w-]+)\.[\w.-]+(?::[0-9]{1,5})?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/iP7pM6/4) or [`^(?!.*(?<=\d\.|@)(?:25[6-9]|26[0-9]|[3-9][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4,})\b)(?:(?:[\w-]+@)?(?:[\w-]+)\.[\w.-]+(?::[0-9]{1,5})?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/iP7pM6/5). There is a slight difference between them: the first requires a `.` or `@` before a number that is greater than 255 to fail the match, and the second one requires a digit + `.` or `@` before that value to fail the match.

Comment: @downvote: Downvoting working and correct answers without leaving a comment is not recommended. You end up with -1 *forever*.

Comment: @Raakesh: I addressed the downvoter. Although they rarely come back with explanations. SO users have different ideas as to what to consider a valid question.